# pjax return false to prevent scroll?

Tags: jquery, pjax

When using pjax with the `duration` variable how can you set a function to prevent the page scroll from changing?

```
var duration = 400
$('a.pjax').pjax('#main', { duration: duration })
$('#main')
  .on('pjax:start', function() { $(this).fadeOut(duration) })
  .on('pjax:waiting', function() {
      $(this)
        .html('<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><img src="waiting.gif" /></div>')
        .show()
    })
  .on('pjax:end',   function() { $(this).fadeIn(duration) })
```

I've been trying the following but no success:

```
$('a.pjax').pjax('#main', { duration: duration }, function(){
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Beware that the `duration` branch is forked from an old version of jquery-pjax and the usage isn't compatible with how jquery-pjax currently works.

Comment: @SeanHogan I'm still running that version, has the affect of that been put into new versions?

Comment: No, and it [doesn't look like a priority for the project anymore](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/17#issuecomment-13248007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stops pjax from auto scrolling:

```
$.pjax.defaults.scrollTo = false;
```